# mysql views get decreased

Tags: php, mysql, image, view

I own a image hosting website and I capture image views using php and mysql.

I use the following code to count the views.

```
include 'mysql.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE ID='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$views=$row['views'];

$query = "UPDATE DB SET views=$views+1 WHERE ID='$id'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($con);
```

views is *mediumint(9)* type field.

I noticed that the views get decreased day by day.can anyone say what is the problem and offer a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you are not really using the page parameter "id" *directly* in the query. To fix this, just insert line  $id = (int) $id;  in your script before the query. Read here why using parameters in queries is a bad idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: You should accept the answer which is appropriate to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use this to update instead:

```
$query = "UPDATE DB SET views=views+1 WHERE ID='$id'";
```

If a page takes a long time to execute, you can have one query overwrite another. Also using this, you might not need to even run the first query - unless you want other info from it.

The reason you are getting an error is that one script is reading the data and grabbing the value, then updating it - based on the value it is storing - but in the meantime other scripts could be updating the row. You could avoid it by using transactions, but that seems utter overkill for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i just made the corrections and it worked. :)

Comment: @msankalpa That's great. My good friend Mihai does offer a great suggestion (and example code even!) for using PDO instead. It is much safer and your code would greatly benefit from upgrading to it :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop using `mysql_*` as those functions are deprecated

You don't need to make 2 queries just to increment a field by 1:

```
$query = "UPDATE DB SET views=views+1 WHERE ID='$id'";
```

and `PDO` example:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE DB SET views=views+1 WHERE ID=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

Read more about [prepared statements and PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)